# Recoding Number to String R

Tags: r, recode

I am new to R and I am trying to recode a numeric variable
which is 1,2,3 to string. I have seen how to do it but I do not know why mine
is not working, maybe it is because it should be from string to number?
This is what I got, and thanks in advance!

```
cars$origin = as.factor(cars$origin)
cars$origin
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 3 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 3 1 1
[35] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 2 1 3 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1
[69] 2 2 3 3 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 3 1 2 1 3 1 1 1
Levels: 1 2 3

cars$origin <- recode(cars$origin, "1='american';2='european';3='japan'")
```

Error: Argument 2 must be named, not unnamed

Comment: Really?? I thought it should be well written but the error remains there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function `factor` has argument `labels` for that:

```
cars$origin = factor(cars$origin, 
   levels = c(1, 2, 3), 
   labels = c("american", "european", "japan"))
```

Comment: That is pretty logic!! The problem has been solved.  Thanks!1

Comment: In this specific case where you already have the levelnumber specified, it works also without specifying the `levels`-parameter.

Comment: Correct, @Jaap. In this specific situation we can skip the `levels` parameter. Still, it answers all questions if you don't know the exact behavior of `factor`.